# Which hand should I punch people with?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

Heavies have the option to punch people with either their right or left hand.

Does it make any difference which hand you punch with as a heavy?

Comment: A correction. Left and right mouse don't matter, but a crit with any fist is always a right uppercut. Thought I'd point that out :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Heavy's melee damage is **[uniform for both hands](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fists)**. It doesn't matter which hand you pick, as long as you hit someone with it. In fact, even the hitboxes are the same - it makes literally no difference.

That said, however, depending on your personal playstyle (going even as far as *how you press the mouse buttons*), you may prefer to use one side - or have a better hit rate with one side. As there is no direct gameplay impact of your choice, you can then *freely use your favourite fist to hammer into other people*.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the mouse button you click does not matter. The right hand is only swung when there is a crit. You can hear the sound that a crit makes every time the right hand swings. If i have my hands backwards let me know, because I have had multiple times where I click with the right mouse button and his left hand swings.